# How to make an API call for IBM Power instance to stop and start

Tags: python, cloud, ibm-cloud, aix

I am working on using IBM Power Cloud Service for creating AIX instance. Most of the APIs work like Get instance, delete instance but the API to modify action fails.

Here is the API Doc :
https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/power-cloud#pcloud-pvminstances-action-post

**It uses cloud IP in the URL . What does that denote?**

This is the python code :

```
import requests
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core import DetailedResponse

class IBMPowerCloud:
    def __init__(self, api_key):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.token = None
        self.headers = None
        self.BASE_URL = "https://us-south.power-iaas.cloud.ibm.com"
        self.CRN = "crn:v1:bluemix:public:power-iaas:us-south:a/XXX:aXXXX::"

def authenticate(self):
    url = "https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token"
    headers = {
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "accept": "application/json",
    }
    data = {
        "grant_type": "urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey",
        "apikey": self.api_key,
    }

    response = self._make_request("POST", url, data=data, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        self.token = response.json()
        self.headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {self.token['access_token']}",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "CRN": self.CRN,
        }
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Authentication Error: {response.status_code}")

def _make_request(self, method, url, data=None, headers=None):
    try:
        response = requests.request(method, url, data=data, headers=headers)
        print(data)
        print(method)
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        raise Exception(f"API Error: {e}")

def get_pvm_instance(self, instance_id) -> DetailedResponse:
    if not self.token or not self.headers:
        self.authenticate()

    cloud_instance_id, pvm_instance_id = instance_id.split("/")
    url = f"{self.BASE_URL}/pcloud/v1/cloud-instances/{cloud_instance_id}/pvm-instances/{pvm_instance_id}"
    response = self._make_request("GET", url, headers=self.headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        result = response.json()
        return DetailedResponse(
            response=result,
            headers=response.headers,
            status_code=response.status_code,
        )
    else:
        raise Exception(f"API Error: {response.status_code}")

def delete_pvm_instance(self, instance_id) -> DetailedResponse:
    if not self.token or not self.headers:
      self.authenticate()

    cloud_instance_id, pvm_instance_id = instance_id.split("/")
    url = f"{self.BASE_URL}/pcloud/v1/cloud-instances/{cloud_instance_id}/pvm-instances/{pvm_instance_id}"
    response = self._make_request("DELETE", url, headers=self.headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        result = response.json()
        return DetailedResponse(
            response=result,
            headers=response.headers,
            status_code=response.status_code,
        )
    else:
        raise Exception(f"API Error: {response.status_code}")

def _perform_instance_action(self, instance_id, action):
    if not self.token or not self.headers:
        self.authenticate()
    data = {
        "action":action,
    }
    print(data)
    cloud_instance_id, pvm_instance_id = instance_id.split("/")
    url = f"{self.BASE_URL}/pcloud/v1/cloud-instances/{cloud_instance_id}/pvm-instances/{pvm_instance_id}/action"
    response = self._make_request("POST", url, data=data, headers=self.headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return DetailedResponse(
            response=response.json(),
            headers=response.headers,
            status_code=response.status_code,
        )
    else:
        raise Exception(f"API Error: {response.status_code}")

def start_pvm_instance(self, instance_id) -> DetailedResponse:
    return self._perform_instance_action(instance_id, "start")

def stop_pvm_instance(self, instance_id) -> DetailedResponse:
    return self._perform_instance_action(instance_id, "stop")
```

Comment: I guess the docs are wrong and the "Cloud IP" should be just the endpoint URL. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I did tried that. It was failing, figured out the issue now. Thanks.

Comment: Document it here or delete your question